# google sheets substitute multiple

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a `google spreadsheet` that I am importing data from a website. When the data is pulled, it has extra quotes and equal signs. I can use the Substitute function to get rid of one of the characters, but when I try to use the substitute function to remove both quotes and text, Sheets only pulls one cell of data.

**Formula:**

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=downloadMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=12504&EventId=4&AwardId=1")
```

**Result:** Pulls all data, but includes extra quotes and = signs.

**Formula:**

```
=Substitute(IMPORTDATA("https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=downloadMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=12504&EventId=4&AwardId=1"),char(61),"")
```

**Result:** Pulls only one cell of data, and only gets rid of equal sign.

**Formula:**

```
=Substitute(Substitute( IMPORTDATA("https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=downloadMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=12504&EventId=4&AwardId=1"),char(61),""),char(34),"")
```

**Result:** Pulls only one cell of data and removes both extra quotes and equal signs.

A work around I have been able to achieve the desired results:
I can use the
**Formula:**

```
=IMPORTDATA("https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=downloadMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=12504&EventId=4&AwardId=1")
```

and then use formulas like:

```
=substitute(substitute(B22,char(34),""),char(61),"")
```

for every cell that has the imported data. It's not very clean though, and if possible I would like to have it done in one step.

One of the complications I will run into at the end of the project is that I am importing the data over my phone's hotspot. The location that I will be in has coverage, but is not very reliable, so any way to keep the amount of data transferred at a minimum would be great.

Link to example spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-cV3llUpZsrjRb4izTXVtDPsTmP15xkWDmfKjPjopDI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also do this: replace the 'download 'parameter in your download url to the word 'get' (see below):

instead of https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=`downloadMatchResultsDetail`&MatchId=12504&EventId=4&AwardId=1

put:

instead of https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=`getMatchResultsDetail`&MatchId=12504&EventId=4&AwardId=1

then just use one function for importhtml:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=getMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=12504&EventId=4&AwardId=1","TABLE",1)
```

Comment: Excellent, I like this even better. It makes it a bit cleaner when I run a query as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=arrayformula(substitute(SUBSTITUTE( IMPORTDATA("https://ct.thecmp.org/app/v1/index.php?do=match&task=downloadMatchResultsDetail&MatchId=12504&EventId=4&AwardId=1") ,char(61) , "" ),char(34),""))
```